# With the Box v2 API, how do I set the current (top) version?

Tags: box-api

Using the v2 Box API, how do I set the most recent version of a file? This is with a premium account. I see that there is the /versions resource, for downloading a specific version of a file, and that now works.  But, If I want to progmatically set an older version as the latest version, how do I do it?

Just to clarify, I don't want to upload a new version, I want to set an older version as the most current.

Reference: http://developers.box.com/docs/

Answer (score 0):

We have not yet implemented this in the V2 API.  It is on our backlog, and will probably be something we deliver in about a month.

It would be good to get your feedback on what your intended use of the API is.  For example, if you do a GET on /files//versions and get an array of 5 versions (numbered 1-5).   Then do a PUT on /files/ and specify that you want what WAS version 3 to now be the current version, should the update timestamp on V3 be changed to be ?  Or should we just re-order the versions?  Would it make sense for a call to /files//versions give you 3,5,4,2,1 as the order instead of the previos 5,4,3,2,1.

Comment: I guess the answer as to setting/resetting timestamps would be what Box does in their UI right now.  Without checking what is done there, I would think the timestamp would remain the same, but the top of the versions stack would point to what was this version 3 file.

Comment: Additionally, since there are only so many versions of a file associated with a file, I would think that a PUT of an older version would add a new version of the file, rather than just setting the file to be the most recent.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to work with Box's version history and perform the "Make current Version" operation (making an old version of a file the most recent version), the V1 API has a make_current_version method (http://developers.box.net/ApiFunction_make_current_version).  An equivalent method will be made available in the V2 API soon, but you can use some V1 calls in the meantime.